# What are the best options for a Wordpress forum?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, forum

I was just wondering what forums are integratable into wordpress or any wordpress forum plugin. What are the best options for both free and paid.

Comment: This question might have been better asked at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com). Would most likely also receive more and better answers. Actually, it has very likely been covered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) it is by the same people behind Wordpress. bbPress can be tightly integrated with a Wordpress blog.